# In Superset, the URLs for sharing are generated with "127.0.0.1:8088" instead of the actual domain, except the "Share Query" button in SQL Lab

Tags: apache-superset

In Superset, there are several places where it's possible to share something: a chart, a dashboard, a specific section in a dashboard, etc.

Except the "*Share Query*" button in SQL Lab that works fine (i.e. generates a working URL with the actual domain) the other places where it's possible to generate a share URL are not working well for me (Superset version 0.35.2): in fact, the generated URLs are like `http://127.0.0.1:80800/r/123`

How can I have them working well as the "Share Query" button in SQL Lab?

(Also temporary hacks by modifying some file on the server would be a good solution at the moment).

Comment: Are you saying sharing sqllab results in: http://www.example.com/superset/sqllab?savedQueryId=2 |  while charts is http://127.0.0.1:80800/r/123 ?

Comment: Close to that: precisely I get "http://example.com/superset/sqllab?id=2" from SQL Lab when I click the "share Query" button, while if I want to share a Chart, or a specific tab in a dashboard, etc. I get "http://127.0.0.1:8088/r/123".

Comment: Could you share the setting you used to set the domain name in SQL Lab/superset_config.py

Comment: Hey, solved: will answer my own question.

Comment: Please share the config settings used so it helps others who have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, the problem was the Host header not set by NGINX (used as reverse-proxy) when receiving the requests.